# Multiple streams on VLCJ

Tags: java, vlcj

So, I've got this code

```
public class MultiThreadedWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    FormatRtsp parser = new FormatRtsp();
    private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Conectar");
    private JButton btnStop = new JButton("Desconectar");
    private JButton btnPause = new JButton("Pausar");
    private MediaPlayerFactory[] factory;
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayer[] mediaPlayer;

    int Video_Width = 500;
    int Video_Height = 300;
    int Num_Video = 4;

    public MultiThreadedWindow() {
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Canvas[] videoCanvas = new Canvas[Num_Video];
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel[] vidPanel = new JPanel[Num_Video];

        for (int i = 0; i < Num_Video; i++) {
            vidPanel[i] = new JPanel();
            videoCanvas[i] = new Canvas();
            vidPanel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Video_Width, Video_Height));
            vidPanel[i].setBackground(Color.black);
            vidPanel[i].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            videoCanvas[i].setBackground(Color.black);
            vidPanel[i].add(videoCanvas[i], BorderLayout.CENTER);
            mainPanel.add(vidPanel[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        factory[i] = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        mediaPlayer[i] = factory[i].newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer[i].setVideoSurface(factory[i].newVideoSurface(videoCanvas[i]));
        mediaPlayer[i].setPlaySubItems(true);
        mediaPlayer[i].addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mediaSubItemAdded(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, libvlc_media_t subItem) {
                List<String> items = mediaPlayer.subItems();
                System.out.println(items);
            }
        });
        }

        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play();
            }
        });

        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stop();
            }
        });

        btnPause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pause();
            }
        });

        topPanel.add(btnPlay);
        topPanel.add(btnStop);
        topPanel.add(btnPause);
    }

    public void start() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        play();
    }

    private void play() {
        mediaPlayer[0].playMedia(parser.formatRtspStream(RTSPADRESS));
        mediaPlayer[1].playMedia(parser.formatRtspStream(RTSPADRESS));
        mediaPlayer[2].playMedia(parser.formatRtspStream(RTSPADRESS));
        mediaPlayer[3].playMedia(parser.formatRtspStream(RTSPADRESS));
    }

    private void stop() {
        mediaPlayer[0].stop();
        mediaPlayer[1].stop();
        mediaPlayer[2].stop();
        mediaPlayer[3].stop();
    }

    private void pause() {
        mediaPlayer[0].pause();
        mediaPlayer[1].pause();
        mediaPlayer[2].pause();
        mediaPlayer[3].pause();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("OK")) {
            this.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

This is a project to display 4 cameras using VLCj. I tried to study the documentation and even saw it here in Stackoverflow over multiple streams, but I found it confusing. I researched a lot but could not identify where it is the nullpointerexception.

And it should display a JFrame with 4 Canvas. I was able to do this same code declaring 4 factorys and 4 mediaplayers, but I do not think this is the right way to do it. I'd like to understand what I'm missing. Thank you.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.MultiThreadedWindow.<init>(MultiThreadedWindow.java:56)
```

Comment: [Here's the source of my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078586/vlcj-creating-multiple-video-panels) but I didn't understand what do I'm missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing an NPE on line 56 because you haven't initialized your array on line 10 (and 9 for that matter).

The other code uses class members rather than an array to hold them all.

```
private MediaPlayerFactory factory0, factory1, factory2, factory3;
private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer0, mediaPlayer1, mediaPlayer2, mediaPlayer3;
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Just to know: Why it can't be initialized on the loop?

Comment: With a primitive array you have to initialize with a size (new arr[4]), so you would have to initialize this before using it in the loop which you certainly can do. However if I were you I would change the  holders to be some impl of the lovely List interface in java, this is a much easier to use (IMO): private List<MediaPlayerFactory> factoryList = new ArrayList<>(); and List<EmbeddedMediaPlayer> mediaPlayerList= new ArrayList<>(); so you are certain the holders are initialized and you get to use lists :)

Comment: Hm... I see. I'm a beginner, I have not used List yet, but I'll study to be able to apply in this case. I want to redo this code now that I understand how it works. Leave it more object-oriented and lighter, remove mistakes from the library itself ... Thanks a lot for the help and the clarification!